# url rewriting help

Tags: mod-rewrite

i am using url rewriting like

```
 RewriteRule ^mobiles/(.*)$ /mobile_rating.php?alias=$1 [L,B]
```

which works well for me like

```
/mobiles/nokia70  /mobile_rating.php?alias=nokia70
```

i need a small change like

```
/mobiles/nokia70  /mobile_rating.php?alias=nokia70&product=mobiles
```

i mean to say like the mobiles in url must be changed to product=mobiles ..how do i do it..any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the product variable is determined from the first part of the URL, this will do it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /mobile_rating.php?alias=$2&product=$1 [L,B]
```

However, I would change the character match from `.*` to something less generic. The above will rewrite `/mobiles/nokia70/abc` to `/mobile_rating.php?alias=abc&product=mobiles/nokia70`.

`[^/]+` will match a string that doesn't contain the forward slash, or if you're always using a strict set of letters/numbers, try `[a-z0-9-]+` which will match any lowercase letter, digit or the hyphen.